# how to compare money in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need use case condition in sql server, the datatype is money, the condition is money>= 100, here is my code:

```
 insert into table1 
(  Col1,
   Col2,
   Col3
) 

select 
 ColA,
 ColB,
 case ColC when ColC >=100 then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

I got an error: Incorrect syntax near '>'. How do I compare money in sql? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
case when ColC >=100 then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

You are mingling the [two forms of the `CASE` expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) (searched and simple). You would only use `CASE ColC ...` when all the match expressions are to have an `=` comparison on them (and then don't specify the operator explicitly).